# Triggering multiple actions synchronously for React Native Router

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I'm using `react-native-router-flux` and I'm trying to trigger multiple actions at once. If I do the following, the drawer closes, but the route doesn't change.

```
Actions.foo();
Actions.refresh({key: 'drawer', open: false});
```

If I do the following, the route changes, but the drawer doesn't close.

```
Actions.refresh({key: 'drawer', open: false});
Actions.foo();
```

I could use a `setTimeout`, but I prefer to avoid `setTimeout` if possible. Are there any other ways?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this without using `setTimeout`?

Comment: I don't remember, we scrapped the project. I think you can use epics/sagas.